# Sum ArrayList to integer

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

I am trying to sum up an `ArrayList` to an integer.

On the `sum += list.get(i);` line I get an error:

> The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Object

```java
JTable j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (i = 0; i < j.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
    list.add(j.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1));
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sum += list.get(i);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

What can I do to sum up the `ArrayList` to an integer?

Comment: `list` contains `Object`s. `sum` is a double. You can't add the two together. You'll have to get the value of `list.get(i)` as a primitive number.

Comment: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();` according to your description should be `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getValueAt` returns an `Object`. If you know it's an `Integer`, you need to explicitly cast it so that Java can treat it as such. E.g.:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(i = 0;i<j.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
{
    list.add((Integer) j.getModel().getValueAt(i,1));
}
```

Now that `list` is a `List<Integer>`, `list.get` will return an `Integer`, not an `Object`, and your second `for` loop should work just fine.

**EDIT:**
According to the comment, the value in model is actually a `String` not an `Integer`. You'll have to convert it to an `Integer` yourself:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(i = 0;i<j.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
{
    list.add(Integer.valueOf((String) j.getModel().getValueAt(i,1)));
}
```

Comment: I added this. Now I get: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

Comment: @Ryneld that means you don't have an `Integer` there. See my edited answer.